# How to use Custom (or albumentation) augmentations on Detectron 2?

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, detectron, albumentations

I have the below code where I'm using default augmentation during training of `Detectron 2` but the problem is that there are very few augmentations that are useful to me.

1. [Here is something like what I to achieve with my own functions](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/issues/3937#issuecomment-1031445235).
2. [This github issue link tries to solve](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/issues/3054#issuecomment-1135429141).

Want to whether it is the right way to do it and also, how could I **Look at the augmented image result** if I want to see what's happening?

```
import detectron2.data.transforms as T
from detectron2.data import detection_utils as utils

def custom_mapper(dataset_dict):
    
    dataset_dict = copy.deepcopy(dataset_dict)
    image = utils.read_image(dataset_dict["file_name"], format="BGR")
    transform_list = [T.RandomBrightness(0.8, 1.2),
                      T.RandomContrast(0.8, 1.2),
                      T.RandomSaturation(0.8, 1.2),
                      ]
    image, transforms = T.apply_transform_gens(transform_list, image)
    dataset_dict["image"] = torch.as_tensor(image.transpose(2, 0, 1).astype("float32"))

    annos = [
        utils.transform_instance_annotations(obj, transforms, image.shape[:2])
        for obj in dataset_dict.pop("annotations")
        if obj.get("iscrowd", 0) == 0
    ]
    instances = utils.annotations_to_instances(annos, image.shape[:2])
    dataset_dict["instances"] = utils.filter_empty_instances(instances)
    return dataset_dict
```

But the problem is that

1. I want to build my custom augmentation or use [albumentations](https://albumentations.ai/docs/examples/example_bboxes/) for the purpose.
2. I don't want to use all of the augmentations every time and there's no probability in the above transformations that I have used. So a way around would be to use something like `OneOf` on individual or a group.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this similar question:
[How to use detectron2's augmentation with datasets loaded using register_coco_instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71774744/how-to-use-detectron2s-augmentation-with-datasets-loaded-using-register-coco-in)

Answer (score 1):

So after running through the code flow and documentation, I found out that Each `Augmentation` class is dependent on the `Transform` class which is inherited from the [fvcore library](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fvcore/blob/main/fvcore/transforms/transform.py#:%7E:text=class%20Transform(metaclass%3DABCMeta)%3A)

Also the same dependency is also defined vaguely [in this highlighted documentation block](https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/augmentation.html#:%7E:text=Three%20basic%20concepts,the%20above%20example.)

Then looking at all the aspects above and then [going through this github PR merge fight thread](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/issues/3054), I sense that I'm on the right track so following [`PILColorTransform`](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/blob/7c2c8fb168a2093ce06a531c1208fba48d2984ec/detectron2/data/transforms/transform.py#L250:%7E:text=class%20PILColorTransform(ColorTransform)%3A) augmentation, I have made this code which works perfectly for custom augmentation

### **1. CUSTOM Augmentations**

```
class GenericWrapperTransform(Transform):
    """
    Generic wrapper for any transform (for color transform only. You can give functionality to apply_coods, apply_segmentation too)
    """

    def __init__(self, custom_function:Callable):
        """
        Args:
            custom_function (Callable): operation to be applied to the image which takes in an ndarray and returns an ndarray.
        """
        if not callable(custom_function):
            raise ValueError("'custom_function' should be callable")
        
        super().__init__()
        self._set_attributes(locals())

    def apply_image(self, img):
        '''
        apply transformation to image array based on the `custom_function`
        '''
        return self.custom_function(img)

    def apply_coords(self, coords):
        '''
        Apply transformations to Bounding Box Coordinates. Currently is won't do anything but we can change this based on our use case
        '''
        return coords

    def inverse(self):
        return NoOpTransform()

    def apply_segmentation(self, segmentation):
        '''
        Apply transformations to segmentation. currently is won't do anything but we can change this based on our use case
        '''
        return segmentation


class CustomAug(Augmentation):
    """
    Given a probability and a custom function, return a GenericWrapperTransform object whose `apply_image`  will be called to perform augmentation
    """

    def __init__(self, custom_function, prob=1.0):
        """
        Args:
            custom_op: Operation to use. Must be a function takes an ndarray and returns an ndarray
            prob (float): probability of applying the function
        """
        super().__init__()
        self._init(locals())

    def get_transform(self, image):
        '''
        Based on probability, choose whether you want to apply the given function or not
        '''
        do = self._rand_range() < self.prob
        if do:
            return GenericWrapperTransform(self.custom_function)
        else:
            return NoOpTransform() # it returns a Transform which just returns the original Image array only


def white(image):
    return np.ones(image.shape, dtype = np.uint8)*255 # returns white Image

def black(image):
    return np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8) # returns black image

def rand(image):
    return np.random.randint(0,256,image.shape, dtype = np.uint8) # returns random image

def default(image):
    return image # returns original image
```

### **2. Implementing `OneOf` like functions**

I looked into the [implementation of `AugmentationList`](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/blob/7c2c8fb168a2093ce06a531c1208fba48d2984ec/detectron2/data/transforms/augmentation.py#:%7E:text=class%20AugmentationList(Augmentation)%3A) and built my own code to generate transformations randomly. Setting `k=1` mimics `OneOf` like functionality.

```
class KRandomAugmentationList(Augmentation):
    """
    Select and Apply "K" augmentations in "RANDOM" order with "Every"  __call__ method invoke
    """
    def __init__(self, augs, k:int = -1):
        """
        Args:
            augs: list of [Augmentation or Transform]
            k: Number of augment to use from the given list in range [1,len_augs]. If None, use all. If it is -1, generate K randomly between [1,len_augs]
        """
        super().__init__()
        self.max_range = len(augs)
        self.k = k
        self.augs = augs # set augs to use as fixed if we have to use same augs everytime
    

    def _setup_augs(self, augs, k:int):
        '''
        Setup the argument list. Generates the list of argument to use from the given list
        args:
            augs: list of [Augmentation or Transform])
            k: Number of augment to use from the given list in range [1,len_augs]. If False, use all. If it is -1, generate K randomly between [1,len_augs]
        '''
        if k == -1: # Generate a random number
            k = np.random.randint(1,len(augs)+1)
        
        elif k is None: # use all
            k = self.max_range

        temp = np.random.choice(augs,k,replace=False) # get k augments randomly
        return [_transform_to_aug(x) for x in temp]

    
    def __call__(self, aug_input) -> Transform:
        tfms = []

        for x in self._setup_augs(self.augs, self.k): # generate auguments to use randomly on the fly
            print(x)
            tfm = x(aug_input)
            tfms.append(tfm)
        return TransformList(tfms)

    def __repr__(self):
        msgs = [str(x) for x in self.augs]
        return "AugmentationList[{}]".format(", ".join(msgs))

    __str__ = __repr__
```

### **3. Putting Everything together**

```
from detectron2.data import transforms as T
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

augs = KRandomAugmentationList(
        [
        # my custom augs
        CustomAug(white), 
        CustomAug(black),
        CustomAug(default),
        CustomAug(rand),
        
        # augs from Detectron
        T.RandomBrightness(0.4, 1.6),
        T.RandomSaturation(0.4, 1.6),
        T.RandomContrast(0.4,1.6),
        T.RandomCrop("absolute", (640, 640)),
        T.RandomFlip(prob=0.5),
        ],
        k = -1)



# Calling the below block multiple times will give you different combinations
# of Augmentations everytime depending on the value of `k`

image = np.array(Image.open("my_image.png")) # RGB image array
input_ = T.AugInput(image, boxes=None, sem_seg = None) # boxes and segments are optional
transform = augs(input_)  # Apply the augmentation
image_transformed = input_.image  # augmented image

Image.fromarray(image_transformed) # show RGB image
```

---

Answer (score -1):

You can easily do both things with `albumentations`.

**Here is an example:**

```
import albumentations as A

def create_transform():
    return A.Compose(
        [
            A.OneOf([
                A.RandomBrightness(p=1),
                A.RandomContrast(limit=.2, p=1)
                ],
                p=.8),
            A.GaussNoise(p=.8),
        ],
    )

def transform_image(image):
    
    transform = create_transform()
    
    transformed = transform(image=image)
    
    transformed_image = transformed["image"]
    
    return transformed_image
```

For every albumentations operation there is a probability parameter `p=1` and for randomly chose a operation between two or more you can use `A.OneOf([],p=.8)`. In my example both `A.OneOf([],p=.8)` and `A.GaussNoise(p=.8)` 80% chance of applying on the image.

**Testing with a random image**

```
import numpy as np

image = np.random.randint(255, size=(24,24)).astype("float32")

# array([[104.,  29., 230.,  68., 134.],
#        [ 43., 162.,  73., 246., 111.],
#        [ 71., 188., 206.,  85., 233.],
#        [105., 178., 190.,  54., 231.],
#        [  0., 116., 169., 244., 178.]], dtype=float32)

transform_image(a)

# array([[1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 1.        , 0.11930324],
#        [1.        , 1.        , 0.        , 0.        , 1.        ],
#        [0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.5334698 , 0.        ],
#        [1.        , 0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 1.        ],
#        [0.        , 0.        , 1.        , 0.        , 1.        ]],
#       dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Yes I know but  but I want to use it in `Detectron2`. Which accepts  `Augmentation` and `Transform` classes only. It also registers the functions to use them later for different tasks like caching, pre fetching etc.